# Attach function as a method to another function in JS

Tags: javascript

Got take-home assignment:
"You need to build a stub for fetch(url) function, which will fail n requests and starting from n+1 will fetch data successfully. Must be way to configure it passing number of requests to be failed (n, required) and optional parameter 'time to wait before resolve/reject'. Also must be the way to reset the request counter invoking fetch.reset(). Just as original fetch(), function should return Promise."
So, we need fetch-like function with a functionality mentioned above. Problem is with fetch.reset() method. Can't figure out how I can attach function to callback function.

So, no problem with all of these except for fetch.reset().

```
function outer (num, time) {
  let count = 1;

  return function fetchIt() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (count > num) {
        count++;
        setTimeout(()=>{resolve('ok');}, time * 1000) // here actual data will be returned/resolved
      } else {
        count++;
        setTimeout(()=>{reject();}, time * 1000)
      }
    })
  }
}

let newFetch = outer(2, 2);

newFetch().then(()=>console.log('ok'), ()=>console.log('not ok')); // 'not ok'
newFetch().then(()=>console.log('ok'), ()=>console.log('not ok')); // 'not ok'
newFetch().then(()=>console.log('ok'), ()=>console.log('not ok')); // 'ok'
```

Now, how can i make newFetch.reset() method to reset counter to 1?
Tried prototype - nope. I think problems are with accessing inner function from outer scope.

Plunk for this stuff:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FiXKyDJ1E2cv8LuUMxRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `fetchIt` to a variable before returning, then add the function on there:

```
function outer (num, time) {
  ...
  let fetchIt = function fetchIt() {
      ...
  }
  fetchIt.reset = function reset() {
      count = 1 // Or whatever you need to do
  }
  return fetchIt
}
```

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere! Kudos for putting in the work yourself, and asking a proper question with enough detail and code so it could be answered!